# How to make a backup of Ubuntu 12.04 full OS

Tags: software-center, hard-drive, backup

How to make a complete operating system backup of Ubuntu without anything missing, to switch it to a different hard drive?

A complete personal usable backup without using untrusted software, exactly like original.

Answer (score 1):

Use [Remastersys](http://www.geekconnection.org/remastersys/ubuntu.html).

Manual Method: Check [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCDCustomization) and [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCDCustomizationFromScratch). It will give you idea about manual method to do the same. However those page are bit too old and are not updated for current version of ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with the help of remastersys
Download the following files

1. http://www.geekconnection.org/remastersys/downloads/remastersys-gtk_3.0.3-1_all.deb
2. http://www.geekconnection.org/remastersys/downloads/remastersys_3.0.3-1_all.deb
3. And as per architecture i.e 32 or 64 bit
   32 bit =>
   http://www.geekconnection.org/remastersys/downloads/remastersys-gui_3.0.3-1_i386.deb
   64 bit =>
   http://www.geekconnection.org/remastersys/downloads/remastersys-gui_3.0.3-1_amd64.deb

Then go to folder where you downloaded them
`cd /path/to/folder/`

Then install them
`sudo dpkg -i *.deb`

It will install some other packages too.

Run the software through dash.
Rest on how to use it can be found here http://www.geekconnection.org/remastersys/ubuntu.html